# C# .NET Framework Library -- where to put unit tests?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

Getting set up for TDD with C# .NET Framework.

I have added a library project to my VS solution and want to add unit tests.
I see that I can add a MSTest project to the solution.

Does this mean that it's better to keep the library in its own solution, rather than having a couple of library projects, and a couple of test projects, plus the main application all in one solution?

In other words, when developing a library, is it best to have one solution for the library and its unit tests, and then another solution for the application that uses the library?

Thanks

Comment: Just keep it in the same solution. A solution is basically just a collection of projects that may or may not depend on each other.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can keep the project for testing in the same solution.